# Searching for a phrase in multiple files chosen by a command

Tags: bash, shell

I want this script to search through each file named by the "find" command, looking for this phrase, given by the user, then simply show where the phrase was found.
So far it ends up saying "grep: file: no such file or directory" after the phrase has been fed to the script.
What's wrong here? Am i using "for" incorrectly?

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(find ./ -mtime -7)
echo What phrase am I looking for:
read waldo
for f in file; 
do
 f=${f:5}
done
for p in file; 
do
 if grep -Fxq $waldo $p
then
 printf "Found phrase in " $p
fi
done
```

Comment: Is `/.` is really intentional ? Don't you mean `.` or `./` ? And indent your code properly

Comment: oh, what a stupid error, fixed and i have the same problem

Comment: You might want to add `-type f` to your find command to avoid grep on directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(find ./ -type f)
echo 'What phrase am I looking for:'
read waldo
for f in $file;
do
 if grep -Fq $waldo $f
 then
  echo "Found phrase in $f"
 fi
done
```

You missed a few '$' here and there, the -x flag for grep only allows matches of an entire line (not sure if that's intended) also I added '-type f' to find so it wouldn't try to match against folders.

You can actually perform the same function simply with one grep command

```
grep -rl 'search phrase' ./
```

Edit: In fact you don't need the first for loop, not sure what it was for.

Comment: Now it works fine until the "found the phrase in" part, it just doesnt show anything...

Comment: The first loop is supposed to erase the "find " part that I believed it injected into the value of file with the command.

Comment: Did you remove the -x flag from grep? it will cause grep to only find matches for a whole line. Also would a simple: "grep -rl 'search phrase' ./" meet your requirements?

Comment: Wooow, the -x was a problem too, you guys are right, it works exactly like i wanted it to.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : (missed `$` sigil on variable use)

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(find ./ -mtime -7)
echo What phrase am I looking for:
read waldo
for f in file; do
  f=${f:5} # what's this ? not used after
done
for p in $file; do
  if grep -Fxq "$waldo" "$p"; then
    printf "Found phrase in $p\n"
  fi
done
```

Use more quotes !

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in file ; do
```

This starts a loop which iterates over 1 value: the string `file`. If you want it to iterate over the string you created earlier, you have to use

```
for f in $file; do
```

It would break for files containing spaces, though. It's better to use the `-exec` argument of `find`:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo -n 'What are you looking for? '
read phrase
find . -mtime -7 -type f -exec grep -l "$phrase" {} +
```

Comment: There's no array at all AFAIK

Comment: Do I need an array? I added the $ and now it stops at "grep: ./ is a directory", thats even stranger! Any idea about what I could fix next?

Comment: @GizmoofArabia: See the update. `-type f` would skip directories.

Comment: New Output:          What am I looking for:
echo
grep: ./czworka.sh:#!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
grep: ./czworka.sh:: No such file or directory
grep: ./czworka.sh:file=$(find: No such file or directory
grep: .: Is a directory
grep: invalid max count

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that keeps the original question of what to search for but avoids the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo What phrase am I looking for:
read waldo

printf "\nSearching...\n\n"
# Use -l for grep to only show the file
# add searching /dev/null to avoid reporting errors from grep
find . -type f -mtime -7 -exec grep -l $waldo {} /dev/null ';'
```